# Using %c in scanf and assigning the value to an int variable in C?

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation, endianness

```
int main()
{
    int i= 0;
    printf("i value is %d\n",i);
    scanf("%c", &i);  // I am giving an input of 255 here

    printf("i after scan %d\n",i); // This prints 50. How???
    
    return 0;
}
```

Can someone explain how does the printf statement give 50? I have a little-endian machine.

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with endianess.

Comment: Given `int i`, then `scanf("%c", &i);` is undefined behavior because you've used the wrong format specifier `%c`, which is for `char` values.

Comment: @AndrewHenle All though this code isn't a perfect scenario, it does not raise any warnings or errors.

Comment: So?  Compilers can not identify undefined behavior.  In fact, they're allowed to assume it never happens.

Comment: @Lundin: On a little-endian system, the byte `scanf` reads is put into the low-end byte of `i`, and the `printf` will show the code for the character “2”. On a big-endian system, the byte is put into the high-end byte, and the `printf` will show the code for the character shifted accordingly.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: Compilers can (and are required to) identify all unidentified behavior resulting from violations of rules in constraints clauses and can identify much run-time undefined behavior. In particular, identifying mismatches between argument types and conversion specifiers in constant format strings is a common compiler feature. Although note that using `%c` to read a byte into an `int` is not undefined behavior; objects may be modified by writing to individual bytes in their representations. The actual undefined behavior is passing an `int *` where a `char *` is expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program won't even compile as `I` is undeclared. I am assuming that it is a typo. Since you are scanning `%c` it will read only one character which is 2 from 255. Now 2 has ascii code of 50 which is being printed.

Comment: yes, that was a typo and I have fixed it. And your solution did make sense. Thank you.